# Azure pipelines running steps inside service containers

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Follow on question from a previous question about targeting containers in Azure pipelines

I am trying to use a playwright container in an Azure pipeline to access the default installed browsers in the image

My main 'azure-pipelines.yml' looks like this

```
trigger: none
pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  

resources:
  containers:
  - container: playwright
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.30.0-focal
  - container: pwsh
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell


stages:
- stage: dev
  displayName: dev
  jobs:
  - template: templates/test.yml
```

And my 'templates.yml' looks like this

```
jobs:
- job: run_tests
  displayName: Test

  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  services:
    playwright: playwright
    pwsh: pwsh

  steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "This is powershell"
      target:
        container: pwsh

    - script: yarn test:integration:ci
      displayName: "Run tests"
      env:
        environment: dev
        CI: true
      target:
        container: playwright
```

But when I run the pipeline, the playwright part does not seem to be working?

```
Running 50 tests using 1 worker
FFFFF

  1) [chromium] › alternativeJourneys.spec.ts:24:5 › Register interest =============================

    browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /home/vsts/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1045/chrome-linux/chrome
    ╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
    ║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
    ║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
    ║                                                                         ║
    ║     npx playwright install                                              ║
    ║                                                                         ║
    ║ <3 Playwright Team                                                      ║
    ╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I have pulled the playwright:v1.30.0-focal image locally and verified that the path mentioned

`/ms-playwright/chromium-1045/chrome-linux/chrome`

does exist. So am wondering if that `/home/vsts/.cache` prefix means this is not running inside the container?

My **yarn.lock** and **package.json** versions also match the **1.30.0** version of the image I am pulling.

I am wondering if my syntax of `target:` is the correct way to make this script run in that container?

If I modify the yaml to this to try to make the whole thing run in the playwright container, then the powershell command fails, again, as I am unsure if my `target:` syntax is the correct way to go?

```
- job: run_tests
        displayName: Test
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest

        container: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.30.0-focal

        services:
          playwright: playwright
          pwsh: pwsh
        steps:
          - powershell: |
              Write-Host "This is powershell"
            target:
              container: pwsh
          - script: yarn test:integration:ci
            displayName: "Run tests"
            env:
              environment: dev
              CI: true
            target:
              container: playwright
```

Is what I am attempting possible and I just have wrong syntax? Or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Appreciate any insight, not a massive amount of hands on with container of Azure pipelines

Many thanks

=============================================================

New info:

It looks like the same hostname for each step

```
- script: |
    echo "Powershell hostname $HOSTNAME"
  target:
    container: pwsh

- script: |
    echo "Playwright hostname $HOSTNAME"
  target:
    container: playwright
```

Yields

Powershell hostname fv-az461-670

and

Playwright hostname fv-az461-670

respectively

fv-az461-670 is the the hostname of the agent host

I don't think I have got this quite right?

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me what output you are getting when you run `echo $HOSTNAME`   inside your agent and inside your container?

Comment: Added hostname output to main post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found this

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/step-target.md

Which had a clearer example of using service containers. Showed my syntax was wrong

Adjusted my template to this and the pipeline worked

```
jobs:
- job:
  displayName: Test

  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  services:
    playwright:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.30.0-focal
    pwsh:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell

  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Powershell"
    target:
      container: pwsh
  - script: yarn test:integration:ci
    displayName: "Run tests"
    env:
      environment: dev
      CI: true
    target:
      container: playwright
```

Thank you